# Can i shutdown Azure App Service to save cost in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Was planning to save cost in Azure .

Can we shutdown Azure App Service to save cost in azure ?

Comment: So as @juunas pointed out, app services are provisioned instances, you get billed even if you stop the webapp. If you re using azure function on a app service consumption plan you wont be charged when youre not using it.

Answer (score -1):

"Yes you can", depending on your configuration you can use the API to remotely control the VM and service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management

Comment: The question is about App Service, not Virtual Machines.

Comment: same difference https://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/starting-and-stopping-azure-app-services-from-your-app.html

Comment: Sure, except that in the case of App Service, billing is not stopped. It only stops the website from serving requests, billing continues based on the tier and instances in the App Service Plan.

Comment: @juunas aha, did not know that... guess you would need to create and remove the instance "on the fly" for the hours you need it... just guessing not familiar with billing